# Average elements in sublists

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list, created by an iterative process, composed of a variable number of sublists all of them with the same number of elements; which is also variable. For example, on one iteration I can have 4 sublists of 3 elements each, like so:

```
list_1 = [[1,3,5], [7,4,9], [3,6,2], [5,4,7]]
```

and in the next iteration of the code I can have:

```
list_2 = [[2,4,8,3,5], [2,4,9,1,3], [1,9,6,3,6]]
```

that is, 3 sublists of 5 elements each.

For a given iteration all sublist will always have the *same* number of elements.

I need a way to generate for iteration `i` a *new* list out of `list_i`, containing the average of all elements located in the same position in each sublist. So in the first case for `list_1`  I'd get:

```
avrg_list = [4.0, 4.25, 5.75]
```

and in the second case for `list_2`:

```
avrg_list = [1.67, 5.67, 7.67, 2.33, 4.67]
```

How can I do this with a flexible code that will adjust itself to different number of sublists and elements?

Comment: You should look at python's functional programming facilities - map, filter, reduce and lambda.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

are you interested in using numpy?

```
In [19]: list_1 = [[1,3,5], [7,4,9], [3,6,2], [5,4,7]]
In [22]: np.mean(list_1, 0)
Out[22]: array([ 4.  ,  4.25,  5.75])
```

Comment: This answer seems even easier than the one by Ashwini. Now I don't know which one to chose.

Comment: you tagged it as python, his is using only standard python (which I find more impressive) I would go with him

Comment: I never thought of `python` and `numpy` as different entities so that doesn't really factor in for me. Both answers are really good, I'll wait a bit to hear from others and see what they vote.

Comment: @Gabriel If you're allowed to use `numpy` then go for it, it is faster than normal python.(But use a numpy array from the start, not list)

Comment: @Gabriel - Numpy and standard Python are separate entities in that some installations of Python don't have numpy.  You also have to import it.  However, I will say this answer is very short/clean (+1 BTW).

Comment: Ok, I've decided to mark this one as accepted since it's simpler and apparently also faster. Also Ashwini has **a lot** of reputation points already so let's give some love to @Hammer :) Thanks guys.

Answer (score 4):

Use `zip` with `*`:

```
>>> [sum(x)/float(len(x)) for x in zip(*list_1)]
[4.0, 4.25, 5.75]
>>> [sum(x)/float(len(x)) for x in zip(*list_2)]
[1.6666666666666667, 5.666666666666667, 7.666666666666667, 2.3333333333333335, 4.666666666666667]
```

From [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

> `zip()` in conjunction with the `*` operator can be used to unzip a list.

```
>>> zip(*list_1)
[(1, 7, 3, 5), (3, 4, 6, 4), (5, 9, 2, 7)]
```

**Timing comparisons:**

```
>>> from itertools import izip
>>> import numpy as np
>>> lis = list_1*1000
>>> arr = np.array(lis)
>>> %timeit np.mean(lis, 0)
10 loops, best of 3: 31.9 ms per loop
>>> %timeit np.mean(arr, 0)
1000 loops, best of 3: 221 us per loop    #clear winner
>>> %timeit [sum(x)/float(len(x)) for x in zip(*lis)]
100 loops, best of 3: 826 us per loop
#itertools.izip is memory efficient.
>>> %timeit [sum(x)/float(len(x)) for x in izip(*lis)]
100 loops, best of 3: 881 us per loop
```

Comment: O.O well that was amazingly fast and efficient. Thank you very much!

Comment: Excellence!  Might want to round it though:  `round(sum(x)/float(len(x)), 2)`